# E-mail sendo enviado em duplicidade para cada contato

Tags: php

Estou enviando uma newsletter para os e-mail´s que tenho cadastrado em meu banco. O envio está sendo feito, mas de forma errônea. Cada contato recebe uma cópia do e-mail de outra pessoa.

O meu código é esse, foram suprimidos valores de conexão:

```
<?php

require_once('../Connections/conexao.php');
// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
include("../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_News = "SELECT * FROM `newsletter` WHERE status = 1 AND fora = 0 ORDER BY id ASC";
$News = mysql_query($query_News, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_News = mysql_fetch_assoc($News);
$totalRows_News = mysql_num_rows($News);    

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// ---------------------------------------------
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = "mail.meusite.com.br"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)
$mail->Username = 'meuemail'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = 'minhasenha'; // Senha do servidor SMTP
$mail->Port = 587;  

// Define o remetente
// ------------------
$mail->From = 'meuemail'; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Newsletters - Móveis Sao Bento"; // Seu nome

// Loop para envio das mensagens
do {

    $id    = $row_News['id'];
    $email = $row_News['email'];

    // Define os destinatário(s)
    // -------------------------
    $mail->AddAddress($email,$nome); // Cliente

    // Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
    // ------------------------------------
     // Define e-mail´s que será(ão) enviado como HTML
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)    

    // Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
    // -----------------------------------
    $mail->Subject  = "Newsletter"; // Assunto da mensagem
    $mail->Body = "<div align=left>
      <style type='text/css'>
        <!--
        .style1 {
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 10px;
        }
        -->
        </style>
          <table width=600 border=0>
            <tr>
              <td width='18%' align='left'>
                <div align='left'></div>
              <div align='left'></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align='left'><p align='left' class='titulos'>
                                   Assunto - Newsletter <br>
                                   E-mail - $email <br />                                  
                                   </p>
                                   <p align='center' class='titulos'>
                                         Esse e-mail foi enviado automaticamete, não responda.<br />
                                        <a href=unsubscribe.php?id=$id>Descadastrar de nossa Newsletter</a>
                                   </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>";


    // Envia o e-mail
    // ---------------
    $status = $mail->Send();

} while ($row_News = mysql_fetch_assoc($News));


if ($status == 1) {
    echo 'Os e-mails foram enviados corretamente ';     
} else {
    echo  'Os e-mails não puderam ser enviados, por favor, tente novamente';
}   

// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
// ----------------------------------
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
```

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está dando um `send` sempre que adiciona um email na lista de envio. Você poderia modificar seu código para ficar parecido com isso:

```
do {
    $id    = $row_News['id'];
    $email = $row_News['email'];
    $nome = $row_News['nome'];
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $nome);
} while (...);

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1';

$mail->Subject  = "Newsletter";
$mail->Body = "...";

$status = $mail->Send();
```

Resumindo, o loop serve apenas para **adicionar** os emails a lista de envio, **NÃO** para enviar. Após ter a lista de emails definida, execute o método `send`, fora do loop.

No entanto, como o @rray falou, desta forma, todos os emails vão aparecer para quem recebeu. Uma forma de resolver isso é enviando a mensagem dentro do loop como você fazia antes, mas limpando a lista de emails. Além disso, você pode setar a mensagem, assunto, etc... fora do loop.

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1';

$mail->Subject  = "Newsletter";
$mail->Body = "...";

do {
    $id    = $row_News['id'];
    $email = $row_News['email'];
    $nome = $row_News['nome'];
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $nome);

    $status = $mail->Send();

    // limpa lista de emails
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
} while (...);
```

Comment: Isso ai vai mandar um único email com todos os endereços expostos, a cada volta do `while` o primeiro e os seguintes vão receber os emails. Acredito que a ideia seja mandar um email por cliente, bastaria dar um `clearAddress` no final laço.

Comment: Olá @rray é exatamente isso que está acontecendo, o clearAddress ficaria fora do loop?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a cada volta do laço um email é adicionado, a primeira pessoa e a seguinte vão receber N vezes a mesma cópia. Se objetivo for mandar um email por pessoa limpe os endereços no final do laço após o envio.

Digamos que sejam 3 clientes, maria, joão e joana. Na primeira volta do laço, maria recberá o email, como o endereço(remetente) não foi zerado/apagado, na segunda volta maria mais joão receberam emails, e na última, maria e joão receberam novamente o email e joana só recberá uma.

Exemplo do problema:

```
do {
    $id    = $row_News['id'];
    $email = $row_News['email'];

    //linhas omitidas ....

    $mail->AddAddress($email,$nome); // Cliente
    $status = $mail->Send();

} while ($row_News = mysql_fetch_assoc($News));


//mais linhas omitidas...

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
```

Para arrumar isso, limpe os endereços com clearAddress():

```
while ($row_News = mysql_fetch_assoc($News)){
//linhas omitidas ....
   $status = $mail->Send();
   $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
   $mail->ClearAttachments();       
}
```

Uma sugestão que deixo é criar um arquivo de template para o email assim você separa o html do código que tem a logica do envio. Pode ver isso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51016/91), que faz o processamento do templete com [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: Olá @rray, se fizer como me disse no exemplo o conteúdo restante do e-mail será abortado, a mensagem que recebi foi essa: Message body empty.

Comment: Mostrei o que precisa ser alterado, (envio do email e a limpeza dos endereços/anexos) as demais linhas continuam. Na prática o que mudou foi a ordem dos bois(linhas do código) :).

Answer (score 0):

Troque a consulta:

`$query_News = "SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE status = 1 AND fora = 0 ORDER BY id ASC";`

Por um **foreach** e deixe somente esse loop. **EXEMPLO**:

```
foreach( $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE status = 1 AND fora = 0 ORDER BY id ASC') as $key => $row) {

$id   = $row->id;
$email= $row->email;

//SEU CÓDIGO SERÁ RODADO A CADA NOVA CONSULTA.

...

}
```