# Como pegar valor de uma variável pelo file_get_contents

Tags: php

Possuo um script que faz o envio de uma newsletter, nesse momento pego uma página .php pelo

```
file_get_contents('news.php')
```

Na página news.php tentei pegar a variável usando isso:

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
```

Nessa página news.php criei um link abaixo do documento onde o usuário pode se decadastrar do boletim, mas não estou conseguindo resgatar o valor do e-mail para passar como parâmetro, meu o link da página news. php está assim:

```
Para cancelar o recebimento deste boletim, <a href="http://www.moveissaobento.com.br/unsubscribe.php?e=<?php echo $email ?>"> Clique aqui </a> e vamos removê-lo da lista imediatamente.
```

O script que envia a news está assim:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

$id = $row['id'];
$email = $row['email'];

$mail->setFrom('emailsdosite@moveissaobento.com.br', 'Newsletter');
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->Subject = 'Envio Newsletter';
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('news.php'), dirname(__FILE__));
$mail->send();
$mail->ClearAddresses();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE newsletter SET enviado = 1 WHERE id = $id");
$stmt->execute();
```

}

Não consegui visualizar uma solução.

Comment: você precisa enviar um post com essas variáveis.

Comment: Você só esqueceu de passar o parâmetro para a página... Tente assim: file_get_contents("news.php?email=$email"); e mude seu $_REQUEST, para $_GET;

Comment: Olá @RafaelWithoeft, recebi uma mensagem de erro ao passar o parâmetro como indicado, veja: Message body empty.

Comment: @adventistapr acredito que isso seja um erro do mailer, não dá pagina... dê uma olhada: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816571/phpmailer-mailer-error-message-body-empty ou já verificou o que está retornando do file_get_contents? var_dump(...)

Comment: Olá @RafaelWithoeft, agora consegui fazer seguindo sua dica.

Comment: @adventistapr Caso queira mais segurança, você pode utilizar POST, mas caso continue a utilizar por GET, recomendo filtrar o que você recebe na página utilizando filter_input (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: Olá @RafaelWithoeft, estou usando o POST, valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode passar as variáveis por post, criando um requisição dessa forma:

```
<?php

$post = http_build_query(array('id' => '9999', 'email' => 'teste@mail.com')); //cria o $_POST
$context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $post,
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        )));



$response = file_get_contents('http://localhost/news.php', false, $context);

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $response;
$mail->send();
$mail->ClearAddresses();
```

Em news.php é so chamar o $_POST como faria em outros arquivos, para saber as chaves deles use `print_r()` que no caso são id e email.

Comment: Olá @rray, valeu pela dica, agora está pegando o valor da variável, que no caso é um e-mail, mas surgiu um problema, não se relacionado a mudança, o e-mail resgatado está assim:
monica.martins.2000%40hotmail.com, sem o sinal de @.

Comment: @adventistapr, está indo como post ou get?

Comment: Olá @rray, está indo por POST

Answer (score 4):

Você está apenas requisitando a página **news.php**, não enviando nenhum parâmetro email;
Tente da seguinte forma:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->Subject  = "Assunto";
$mail->Body = file_get_contents("news.php?email=$email");
$mail->AltBody = "Corpo da Mensagem!";
$send = $mail->Send();
if ($send) {
    echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
}
```

E mude seu `$_REQUEST` para `$_GET` e não esqueça de filtrar o que você recebe utilizando filter_input

```
Exemplo: filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php

> - Caso queira usar POST, recomendo a leitura: [Utilizando POST com
>     file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents)
> - Se precisar de mais informações sobre o PHPMailer [Enviar e-mails pelo
>     PHPMailer](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer/)